# How to set up backups for MySQL databases a windows server?

Tags: backup, mysql, windows-server-2003, data-backup

I am new to MySQL, I have used MS SQL Server up to this point, so forgive my ignorance.

We are hosting on a Rackspace dedicated server and they can set up nightly backups on a directory. Currently, we are backing up all our SQL Server MDF and LDF files this way. I would like to do the same with MySQL, but I don't know enough about the file structure for MySQL databases. I would like to know where the important MySQL files that I need to backup are located.

Is there anything else I need to do in order to create good backups for MySQL. Do I need to set up some sort of regular DUMP process or something? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We would recommend our backup tool [MySql Backup And Ftp (MySqlBF)](http://mysqlbackupftp.com/). MySqlBF allows to schedule backups using a Windows Task Scheduler or a custom windows service for a complex backup scenarios.

It supports connecting securely over an SSH connection and has such a unique feature as creating a backup via phpMyAdmin. The tool allows to archive, encrypt and save backups to HDD, FTP, Network or most popular cloud storage services (Dropbox, Amazon S3, Google Drive, SkyDrive, Box) and sends email notifications on success or failure.

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database engine you are using (MySQL most frequently uses MyISAM or InnoDB).  For the best information, you should start with the MySQL documentation for the version of MySQL you are running ([MySQL 5.1 backup and recovery documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-and-recovery.html)).  You should not be manually copying files that are in use as some databases will not flush changes to the disk without being explicitly told to do so.

Answer (score 0):

there is a really easy way to backup mysql using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) Run this once a night and back up the resultant file.

Answer (score -1):

MYSQLIBF won't work with Windows server 2003

Comment: Can you cite your source for this?

Comment: MYSQLIBF compatibility **MySql 5.0 and higher
MySql 4.1
phpMyAdmin 3.3, phpMyAdmin 3.4 (if connecting through phpMyAdmin)
Win2000, WinXP, Win2003, Windows Vista, Win2008, Windows 7**